# Replace string not in given regex java

Tags: java, regex

I try to replace string which not found in given regex.

`Regex: (^.{1})|((.{1})(@.*))`

Eg: If given input is `dineshkani.n@gmail.com` the above regex will extract `"d", "n@gmail.com"`. I try to replace characters other than this regex find. I tried to get `d**********n@gmail.com`

Is there any way to replace like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if an email was `dn@gmail.com`?

Comment: Probably `s.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?=.+@)", "*")`

Comment: or `\\G.(?!@)` to include 2 letter local parts. https://regex101.com/r/DzOXbF/1

Comment: try this https://ideone.com/AtHvML

Comment: @anubhava if an email was 1 or 2 characters before the domain, that would likely produce a different result.

Comment: My bad @notyou, better to use [`str = str.replaceAll("(?!^).(?=[^@]+@)", "*");`](https://regex101.com/r/DzOXbF/2)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you join those parts together? In Java using join method:

`String email = String.join("*****",arrayOfSplits);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace characters that exist between two anchor points using a regular expression? Yes.

Take a look at the helpful resources below.

[Start of String and End of String Anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

[SO Question about obfuscating emails with REGEX patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25295881/obfuscate-email)

You are on the right path. Your pattern should contain at least 3 [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html). The first capture group will be the first character in the string, email address in your example. The second capture group will be the characters from position 2 to the penultimate position before the `@` symbol. And the third capture group will be the rest of the characters. Using your email as an example:

```
     [d]              [ineshkani.]       [n@gmail.com]
Capture group 1 --- Capture group 2 --- Capture group 3
```

Now that he groups are captured properly, we want to perform a replacement on capture group 2 that will replace each char with some obfuscation value, * for example. That will require a [back reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to group 2.

```
([\w|\d]{1})  # This says match either a word or digit char occurring once
([\S]+)       # Match a non whitespace character with a greedy qualifier
(\S{1}\@\S+)  # Match a non whitespace character then an '@' then the rest of the characters until whitespace is found.
```

Now you will need to use the backreference to group 2 in your Java replace function. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277157/java-regex-replace-with-capturing-group) for a good example of ways to perform regex replace on capture groups. You will need to use `.replaceAll()` and pass the capture group and the replacement string. 
I hope this helps you solve your problem and understand what is going on when you use regular expressions to replace strings in Java.

For more information on a [greedy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) see the Regex Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier to not use `regex` at all.

Why not just use a `StringBuilder` and just look from `1 to lastIndexOf("@") - 1` and set the char as `*`

```
String email = "dineshkani.n@gmail.com";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(email);
int mp = sb.lastIndexOf("@");

for (int i = 1; i < mp - 1; i++) {
    sb.setCharAt(i, '*');
}
```

**Output:**

> d**********n@gmail.com

*Note*: as mentioned in the comments, you'll have to check with this solution if the email is something like `dn@gmail.com`, it will just print that as is.